# How to define property which would allow me to call other Component's method?

Tags: typescript, cocoscreator

I am creating a Component and in it I might need to call some other component's method, but I don't know in advance, which component it will be, so I guess `"cc.Event"` is the best candidate for my task.

When I do it this way, it won't work:

```
@ccclass
export default class Helloworld extends cc.Component {

    @property({ type: cc.Event })
    public event: cc.Event = new cc.Event("", true);

}
```

But I'd like to do it just like we have it in CCButton: 
[image: event example in properties bar]

How can I achieve that? I looked up in `CCButton` sources, I can see that it points to `inspector.js`, but I could not find this inspector file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works.

```
@ccclass
export default class Helloworld extends cc.Component {
    mySuperDuperFunction(_ev, customparam) {
        cc.log("hi , i am super duper !",_ev, customparam); // log will output on debug compile.
    }
}
```

1. Drag this as a component to your node
2. Add this node to your buttons events
3. Choose `HelloWorld` for the component combo
4. Choose `mySuperDuperFunction` from the list